# C# class, JSON serialization into single string

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Say, we have an data structure in C# like these:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyInner
{
    [DataMember]
    public string propertyOne { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string propertyTwo { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyOuter
{
    [DataMember]
    public string propertyOne { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public MyInner propertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to serialize the  MyOuter object like this:

```
    {"propertyOne": "p1", "propertyTwo": "property one value;property two value"}
```

Rather than this:

```
{"propertyOne": "p1", "propertyTwo": { "propertyOne" : "property one value", "propertyTwo": "property two value" }}
```

I mean, I would like to be able to serialize an object like it was a string property... Is there a way to do it?

Thanks,
Dario

Comment: Are you open to using JSON.NET? If so, you could do this with a custom converter

Comment: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: You'd like to serialize property two as an array? Are you going to need to de-serialize it back to an object?

Comment: Ok, I used newtonsoft as Greg suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what serializer you are using, so the following will work for both Json.NET and `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

What you can do is add a proxy property to the outer class, private or public as you prefer, returning the inner class as a string.  Then mark the original property as `[IgnoreDataMember]` and the proxy property as `[DataMember(Name="propertyTwo")]` along these lines:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyInner
{
    public static string ConvertToString(MyInner myInner)
    {
        if (myInner == null)
            return null;
        return myInner.ToString();
    }

    public static MyInner ConvertFromString(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        var firstIndex = value.IndexOf(';');
        if (firstIndex < 0)
            return new MyInner { propertyOne = value, propertyTwo = string.Empty };
        else
            return new MyInner { propertyOne = value.Substring(0, firstIndex), propertyTwo = value.Substring(firstIndex + 1, value.Length - firstIndex - 1) };
    }


    [DataMember]
    public string propertyOne { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string propertyTwo { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0};{1}", propertyOne, propertyTwo);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyOuter
{
    [DataMember]
    public string propertyOne { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public MyInner propertyTwo { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="propertyTwo")]
    string propertyTwoText
    {
        get
        {
            return MyInner.ConvertToString(propertyTwo);
        }
        set
        {
            propertyTwo = MyInner.ConvertFromString(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to decide what to do about `MyInner` property values containing the `;` character.  Do you want to escape them or throw an exception for them?  You could also consider [creating a `TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) for your inner class for general use.